# Why does this block of printed text not format correctly?

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, formatting

I am trying to print a statement that looks like this:

- ...................
- ...................
- ...................

but it is looking like this:

- .........
- ...................
- ...................
- .........

could you help me by debugging my code, I removed all of the \ns but it does not seem to work, here is my code, thanks:

```
with fileinput.input('data.csv') as data:

for row in data:
    row.rstrip('\n')
    input.append(row)
    rows.append(row)

def fill_row():
    for i in range(0, rows.__len__()):
        rows[i].rstrip('\n')
        rows[i] += input[i].rstrip('\n')

fill_row()

for i in rows:
    print(i)
```

my fill_row function is supposed to add the string from input to rows (making the pattern increase in width since it is a 2d array), which works, but it is disaligned by one set.

Comment: What's your data.csv like?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/deTHY7wy